# How to check if a Map contains a given value in Apex Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

When raising this question to https://chat.openai.com/chat, this source of info suggests that I can use a method myMap.contains() with the following example:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new Map<String, Integer>();
map.put('key1', 1);
map.put('key2', 2);
map.put('key3', 3);

// Check if the map contains the value 2
Boolean containsValue = map.containsValue(2); // returns true

// Check if the map contains the value 4
containsValue = map.containsValue(4); // returns false
```

But when checking Salesforce soap api for class Map, I do not see any .containsValue() method: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_methods

So, I think that the AI of https://chat.openai.com/chat might be wrong.

How can I verify, with apex, if a given value is contained in a Map?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map has a [`values()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_values) method that returns a List containing every value in the map.
If you have to check only one value, you could just call [`contains()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_contains) on that list, while if you have to check multiple values you should create a new Set with those values then call [`contains()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_set.htm#apex_System_Set_contains) (or `containsAll()`).

```java
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
myMap.put('key1', 1);
myMap.put('key2', 2);
myMap.put('key3', 3);

List<Integer> mapValues = myMap.values();
System.debug(mapValues.contains(1)); // true

Set<Integer> mapValueSet = new Set<Integer>(mapValues);
System.debug(mapValueSet.contains(2)); // true
System.debug(mapValueSet.contains(5)); // false
```

Keep in mind that `List.contains()` runs in linear time (`O(n)`) while `Set.contains()` runs in constant time (`O(1)`).